# A free software for recording classes with high quality

Tags: teaching

Could you please recommend a **good free** software for recoding my screen. I want to record a lecture and upload it to YouTube. I am looking for a software that can allow me to **pause** while recording. I want to record the screen and my voice with high quality.

Comment: There was a faq with a link at the top of the page... but it is no longer there otherwise I would point you to that... however software, free or not, is also linked to good equipment...

Comment: See https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145548/72855

Comment: @SolarMike sorry I don't understand your point

Comment: Which point don't you understand and why?

Comment: or you can read this: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/10214/72855

Comment: The quality of voice recording is mostly determined by your hardware equipment. Get a good microphone and learn how to use it.

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonic Thanks for your addition. I think u don't read the question. I am asking about software not harware

Comment: I don't think you understand... I am recording my voice and use several bits of software all free with the in-built microphone on my macbook pro and get very good results. The point I made about quality hardware still stands.

Comment: Beware of quality that is higher than needed. It increases bandwidth. If everyone does this there will be problems. Netflix has finally recognized this problem with HD quality video.

Comment: @HebaMohsen, Jitsi, and matrix is a good open source alternative, it has videoconference, accommodating up to 50 person for video conference room, it is also used by French government as far as I know https://jitsi.org/jitsi-meet/

Comment: @Buffy That's a good point, but I think they were referring to a different type of quality. For a given bandwidth, using a cheap ($25-$50) dedicated microphone instead of a laptop's builtin microphone will still make a substantial improvement. Background noise, static, inconsistent levels, etc, are all really distracting in video presentations, and a dedicated microphone can really help to reduce these types of issues.

Comment: @anjama Sound quality probably isn't a big contributor to bandwidth issues. For video you need to find a balance.

Comment: @Buffy I had assumed your comment was in the context of the hardware related comments about quality above, which I in turn assumed was primarily about microphones (but I now suppose could have also been about screen resolution and processing ability of the computer).

Answer (score 3):

Try Zoom. I've been doing exactly what you described, sharing my screen with a PDF pulled up and recording me talking through/over it, for my mathematics course.

Answer (score 3):

[OBS (Open Broadcaster Software)](https://obsproject.com/) is a free and open source software application for video recording and streaming. It's commonly used by video game streamers for Twitch, Youtube, etc, but is perfectly good for what you want to do and has tons of control options, including setting hotkeys that allow you to start/pause recording (requires version 24 or newer). OBS is supported on Windows, macOS, and Linux.